# runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0ba for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, linked-list, stack

> Line 171: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0ba for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h)
> 0xbebebebebebec0ba: note: pointer points here
>
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_deque.h:180:16

i was solving this problem on leetcode
[Link to question](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers-ii/)

and my approach was to use 2 stacks to store values of 2 linkedlist and then pop them one by one while counting the sum at the same time then I planned to save my sum in a vector named ans and then again change the value of linkedlist by assigning it the value of vector.

this is my code:

```
ListNode* addll(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2, vector<int> ans)
{
    ListNode* temp;
    temp=l1;
    int i=0;
    int sizee=ans.size();
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        temp->val=ans[i];
        i++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(i<sizee)
    {
        temp=l1;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        l2->val=ans[i];
        temp->next=l2;
        l2->next=NULL;
        
    }
    return l1;
}




ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    stack<int> s1;
    stack<int> s2;
    ListNode *temp=l1;
    vector<int> ans;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        s1.push(temp->val);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp=l2;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        s2.push(temp->val);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    int carry=0;
    while(!s2.empty() && !s1.empty())
    {
        if(s1.top()+s2.top()+carry<10)
        {
            ans.push_back(carry+s1.top()+s2.top());
            carry=0;
            s1.pop();
            s2.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            ans.push_back((carry+s1.top()+s2.top())%10);
            carry=1;
            s1.pop();
            s2.pop();
            
        }
    }
    int j;
    while(!s2.empty())
    {
        j=s2.top()+carry;
        if(j<10)
        {
            ans.push_back(j);
            carry=0;
        }
        else
        {
            j=j%10;
            ans.push_back(j);
            carry=1;
        }
      
        s2.pop();
    }
    while(!s1.empty())
    {
      
        j=s2.top()+carry;
        if(j<10)
        {
            ans.push_back(j);
            carry=0;
        }
        else
        {
            j=j%10;
            ans.push_back(j);
            carry=1;
        }
      
        s2.pop();
    }
    if(carry!=0)
    {
        ans.push_back(carry);
        carry=0;
    }
    reverse(ans.begin(),ans.end());
    int size1=0,size2=0;
    temp=l1;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        size1++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp=l2;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        size2++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(size1>size2)
    {
        return addll(l1,l2,ans);
    }
    else
    {
        return addll(l2,l1,ans);
    }
}
};
```

the implementation part has no issues I have checked it myself the only issue which I am getting is over here.

```
 while(!s2.empty())
    {
        j=s2.top()+carry;
        if(j<10)
        {
            ans.push_back(j);
            carry=0;
        }
        else
        {
            j=j%10;
            ans.push_back(j);
            carry=1;
        }
      
        s2.pop();
    }
    while(!s1.empty())
    {
      
        j=s2.top()+carry;
        if(j<10)
        {
            ans.push_back(j);
            carry=0;
        }
        else
        {
            j=j%10;
            ans.push_back(j);
            carry=1;
        }
      
        s2.pop();
    }
```

it is giving me a runtime error but when I changed it to

```
 while(!s2.empty())
    {
        ans.push_back(s2.top()+carry);
        carry=0;
        s2.pop();
    }
    while(!s1.empty())
    {
        ans.push_back(s1.top()+carry);
        carry=0;
        s1.pop();
    }
```

the runtime error disappeared but obviously, it gave me a wrong answer because of its wrong logic. Can someone please help me find the bug in the above program because this is an error that I have never seen before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `s2` instead of `s1` in this part:

```cpp
while(!s1.empty())
    {
      
        j=s2.top()+carry; // here
        if(j<10)
        {
            ans.push_back(j);
            carry=0;
        }
        else
        {
            j=j%10;
            ans.push_back(j);
            carry=1;
        }
      
        s2.pop(); // and here
    }
```